# for some reason, when setting language=csharp, the files generated give me build errors?

Tags: c#

I started learning antlr just a few days ago, playing around with the antlr plugin for Jetbrains Rider IDE, the tree thing parsed my code correctly and everything looked amazing and when it came to compile the g4 file into source code that I can use, for some reason it won't work.

I've gone back and forth on the manual trying to get it to work, no luck there.

Here's the g4 file in question

```
grammar CubeScript;

program: line* EOF;

line: statement | ifBlock | whileBlock;

statement : assignment #assignmentexpr
    | functionCall ';'#functioncallstatement
    // defining string should end with ;
    | 'def' IDENTIFIER '=' STRING ';' #definingstringexpr
    // using statement should end with ;
    | 'using' IDENTIFIER ';' #usingstringexpr
    //using statement with the . 
    | 'using' '.' IDENTIFIER ';' #usingstringexpr
    //print(varible) should end with ;
    //string
    | 'string' IDENTIFIER '='  STRING  ';' #stringexpr
    // defining blocks of code should end with ;
    | ENTRY IDENTIFIER '(' (IDENTIFIER (',' IDENTIFIER)*)? ')' block  #definingfunctionexpr
    // namespace should end with ;
    | 'House' ':' IDENTIFIER ';' #namespaceexpr
    // math operations should end with ;
    | expression ';' #expressionstatement
    // math operations 
    | INTEGER '+' INTEGER  #expressionexpr
    // int operations
    | INTEGER '-' INTEGER  #expressionexpr
    // int operations
    | INTEGER '*' INTEGER  #expressionexpr
    // int define
    | 'int' IDENTIFIER '=' INTEGER ';' #intexpr
    // float define
    | 'float' IDENTIFIER '=' FLOAT ';' #floatexpr
    // float operations
    | FLOAT '+' FLOAT  #expressionexpr
    // float operations
    | FLOAT '-' FLOAT  #expressionexpr
    // string array, string{int} identifier = //say io.read();
    | 'string' IDENTIFIER? '{' IDENTIFIER? '}' IDENTIFIER? '=' functionCall';' #stringarrayexpr
    //foreach
    | 'foreach' '(' IDENTIFIER 'in' IDENTIFIER ')'block #foreachexpr
    //print with math operations
    | 'print' '(' expression ')' ';' #printexpr
    //print with identifire
    | 'print' '(' IDENTIFIER ')' ';' #printexpr
    
    ;
ifBlock: 'if' expression block ('else' elseifBlock)?;

elseifBlock: block | ifBlock;

whileBlock: WHILE expression block ('else' elseifBlock)?;


WHILE: 'while' | 'until';
assignment: IDENTIFIER '=' expression;

//function call with support for . 
functionCall: IDENTIFIER '(' (expression (',' expression)*)? ')' #functioncallexprs
    | IDENTIFIER '.' IDENTIFIER '(' (expression (',' expression)*)? ')' #functioncallexprs
    ;


block: '{' line* '}';
expression
    : constant #constantexpr
    | IDENTIFIER #identifierexpr
    | functionCall #functioncallexpr
    | '(' expression ')' #parenthesisexpr
    | '!' expression #notexpr
    | expression multOp expression #multexpr
    | expression addOp expression #addexpr
    | expression cmpOp expression #cmpexpr
    | expression boolOp expression #boolexpr
    ;
Comment
  :  ('//' ~( '\r' | '\n' )*
    |  '/*' .*? '*/'
      |  '#' ~( '\r' | '\n' )*)
      -> skip
  ;    
multOp: '*' | '/' | '%';
addOp: '+' | '-';
cmpOp: '<' | '>' | '<=' | '>=' | '==' | '!=';
boolOp: BOOL_OPERATOR;

BOOL_OPERATOR: 'and' | 'or' | 'xor';
constant : INTEGER | FLOAT | STRING | BOOL | NULL;

INTEGER: [0-9]+;
FLOAT: [0-9]* '.' [0-9]+;
fragment ESC: '\\' (["\\/bfnrt] | UNICODE);
fragment UNICODE: 'u' HEX HEX HEX HEX;
fragment HEX: [0-9a-fA-F];
fragment SAFE: ~["\\\u0000-\u001F];
STRING: '"' (ESC | SAFE)* '"';
BOOL: 'true' | 'false';
NULL: 'null';
WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
ENTRY: 'struct' | 'class' ; 


IDENTIFIER: [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*;`
```

And here are the errors:

> 

0>CubeScriptLexer.cs(94,27): Error CS0115 : 'CubeScriptLexer.TokenNames': no suitable method found to override
0>CubeScriptLexer.cs(117,25): Error CS1715 : 'CubeScriptLexer.SerializedAtn': type must be 'int[]' to match overridden member 'Recognizer<int, LexerATNSimulator>.SerializedAtn'
0>CubeScriptParser.cs(87,27): Error CS0115 : 'CubeScriptParser.TokenNames': no suitable method found to override
0>CubeScriptParser.cs(108,25): Error CS1715 : 'CubeScriptParser.SerializedAtn': type must be 'int[]' to match overridden member 'Recognizer<IToken, ParserATNSimulator>.SerializedAtn'
0>------- Finished building project: ProtoGram. Succeeded: False. Errors: 4. Warnings: 0```

I'm using the latest version of antlr4.runtime and antlr4 from nuget available from jetbrains rider IDE

I'm using the latest version of the IDE, hitting compile or build, whatever you want to call it, it doesnt even let me compile without getting errors, I even went and asked chatGPT and github copilot for some answers and they didn't return anything good..

I'm confused on what to do now. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: **Typo alert**: it's an `INTEGER` - not an "INTERGER" (no "R" before the "G") ....

Comment: Please trim unnecessary error log info, the most important part comes at the bottom `Error CS1715 : 'CubeScriptParser.SerializedAtn': type must be 'int[]' to match overridden member 'Recognizer<IToken, ParserATNSimulator>.SerializedAtn' 0>` which sounds like you are misusing a method in the C# code that is calling this grammar file

Comment: If you generated the parser and lexer through the Antlr plugin UI in the IDE, then the code is from version 4.13.1 of the Antlr Tool. You can check this by looking at the first line (a comment) of the two .cs files generated. The packages [antlr4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Antlr4) and [antlr4.runtime](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Antlr4.Runtime) are for the old and unsupported "antlr4cs". They are incompatible with the generated code. Do not use these packages. Instead, reference [antlr4.runtime.standard](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Antlr4.Runtime.Standard), version 4.13.1.

Comment: Further, I would not manually generate the parser and lexer .cs files. An IDE is not a build tool! It's used to navigate around and edit the .g4. Use [Antlr4BuildTasks](https://github.com/kaby76/Antlr4BuildTasks) to automatically generate the parser and lexer source (remove the "gen" directory that the plugin creates). Antlr4BuildTasks downloads a JRE and the appropriate Antlr Tool .jar file so you never get a version skew between tool and runtime.

Comment: thanks for the info! ill try changing the name for the typo and get runtime.standard!